# how do I succinctly create a new dataframe column based on matching existing column values with list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in a `dataframe` by matching the values in an existing column's values with a predefined list of values. I have two approaches to this below. Both run but dont give me exactly what I want. I prefer the first approach over the second but not sure where I am going wrong with both. I want the solution to be succinct without having to write out alot of `np.where` statements.

First approach:

```
words = [['one man ran','two men ran','three men ran'],['red balloons','white shirt','blue dress']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(words, columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])

search_words1 = ['three','blue']

def columns(search_words1):
    for i in search_words1:
        return "".join(np.where((df3['col3'].str.contains(i)), i, ""))
        
    
df3['col4'] = df3['col3'].apply(lambda x: columns(x))
df3
```

incomplete result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
0   one man ran two men ran three men ran   t
1   red balloons    white shirt blue dress  b
```

Second approach:

```
search_words1 = ['three','blue']

def my_comments(search_words1):
        return "".join([i for i in search_words1 if any(i in x for x in df3['col3'])])
    

df3['col4'] = df3['col3'].apply(lambda x: my_comments(x))
df3
```

incomplete result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
0   one man ran two men ran three men ran   three men ran
1   red balloons    white shirt blue dress  blue dress
```

Desired output for both approaches:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
0   one man ran two men ran three men ran   three
1   red balloons    white shirt blue dress  blue
```

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: @enke Added desired output. thanks.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract`: create a regex pattern of your search words and try to extract the matched pattern:

```
pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(search_words1)})\b"
df3['col4'] = df3['col3'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Pattern:

```
>>> print(pattern)
\b(man|red)\b
```

`\b` matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. The `( )` is the capture group.

Comment: @hector.h2913. The problem here is your search_words does not contain any matching values in the `col3` column.

Comment: thanks. can you explain the syntax in the outer parenthesis, specifically the `f` part? so when i try your solution I get Nan in both rows of `col4`.

Comment: `man` and `red` are not present in your third column.

Comment: `f` is for [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and `r` for raw strings (avoid to use escape sequence like `\\b`)

Comment: Retry the code with `search_words1 = ['men','blue']`

Comment: thanks for the catch of man and red not being in the third column. I edited this post and my code. It works great now! Very succinct, thanks.

Comment: @ Corralien Accepted. I am now trying to get not just one word but in some cases I may need two words that could be consecutive or non consecutive words. for example if I had `three ran` in my `search_words1`, I want result `three ran` in position `0 : col4`

Comment: It's really more complicated. Maybe a first workaround can be : `search_words1 = ['three .* ran']` but it will also extract 'men'